# How to force change the last modified date attribute while saving a text file in python

Tags: python, file, date, attributes

I am saving a text file in python after processing it as follows:

```
outputfile = dirname.split(".")[0] + ".txt"
ProcessedFile.to_csv(outputfile, esp='')
```

This file takes by default today's date as the last modified date. Is there a way I can change this and force-give it my own desired last modified date?

Comment: Use `os.utime()` to set the file timestamps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
outputfile = dirname.split(".")[0] + ".txt"
ProcessedFile.to_csv(outputfile, esp='')
os.utime(outputfile, (56000000, 56000000))
```

In os.utime(outputfile, (atime_ns, mtime_ns)), atime_ns is access time in nanoseconds and mtime_ns is modified time in nanoseconds.

In this example, 56000000 corresponds to the following:

Date in India timezone*: 10/11/1971, 9:03:20 AM

Date in Los Angeles*: 10/10/1971, 8:33:20 PM

Date in Berlin* :10/11/1971, 9:03:20 AM

Date in Beijing*: 10/11/1971, 10:33:20 AM

Date in New York* :10/10/1971, 10:33:20 PM

It will change last modified and access date of the file you are dealing with. You may find the reference for os.utime on https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`os.utime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.utime):

```
import os
os.utime(path_to_file, (access_time, modification_time))
```